# Can I protect my extension from being republished by someone else?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am going to upload my extension to chrome web store.

My question is:
Can I tell google to not allow extension installation if it wasn't installed from my item?

Is there another way to protect my extension?

Without code obfuscation/minifiying?

Comment: AFAIK, you can report other extension if you believed that they are using the code from your app. For your other question, I'm not sure if there are any other way to protect your extension other than obfuscation/minifying your code.

Comment: I am investigating the same questions. One possible option is to put the main code into a web assembly. This makes it difficult for anyone to copy. In your assembly I am sure there will be a way to make sure the rest of the code is yours, e.g. comparing a hash value of the calling file.